# Efficient way in Excel of picking a label based on a list of cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

How do you write an Excel formula that returns a label associated with the cell with the largest value?

I'm basically trying to do a nested if/else or switch statement in Excel, like:

```
if cell1 > cell2 and cell1 > cell 3:
    show "Do X"
elif cell2 > cell3:
    show "Do Y"
elif cell3 is greatest:
    show "Do Z"
```

Currently, I'm using the [`IFS()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ifs-function-36329a26-37b2-467c-972b-4a39bd951d45) function, but it's getting a little unwieldy with a long list of cells to compare.

Comment: What do you mean by label?

Answer (score 0):

To tell the ADDRESS of the cell that has the largest value in a table:

`=CELL("address",OFFSET(A1,0,MATCH(MAX(A1:A9),A1:A9,0)))`
For the table being `A1:A9`